When modifying \@startsection, tag structure changed
When I modifying \@startsection in the cls for getting no space in the above stacked head (\section followed immediately \subsection) the tag structure changed to <p> tag instead of <sect><H1>

I Copied and modified \@startsection from latex-lab-testphase-sec.sty
\def\@startsection#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
  \par
  \@tempskipa #4\relax
  \@afterindenttrue
  \ifdim \@tempskipa <\z@
    \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \@afterindentfalse
  \fi
  \if@nobreak
    \vspace*{-8pt}
    \everypar{}%
  \else
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace\@tempskipa
  \fi
  \tag_tool:n { sec-start=#1}%new
  \@ifstar
    {\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}%
    {\@dblarg{\@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}}

then also i am getting wrong structure, how to get the correct structure.
I am using lualatex-dev with the latest version of tagpdf.sty (tagpdf-base 2024-09-16 v0.99f)
MWE:
\DocumentMetadata
  {pdfversion=1.7,
   testphase={phase-III,table}
  }

\tagpdfsetup{role/map-tags=pdf}

\documentclass{article}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}


\makeatletter
\def\@startsection#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
  \par
  \@tempskipa #4\relax
  \@afterindenttrue
  \ifdim \@tempskipa <\z@
    \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \@afterindentfalse
  \fi
  \if@nobreak
    \ifnum#2=2
        \vspace*{-8pt}  
    \fi
    \everypar{}%
  \else
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace\@tempskipa
  \fi
  \@ifstar
    {\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}%
    {\@dblarg{\@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{tes title}


\maketitle



\section{Section title}
\subsection{Stacked B Head}

Hello.

\subsection{Sub Section title}

Sub Section title

\subsubsection{3rd Section title}

3rd Section title

\paragraph{4th Section title}

4th Section title

\subparagraph{5th Section title}

5th Section title


\begin{quote}
quatoation text

quatoation text
\end{quote}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 1st level

\item 2nd level

\item 3rd level
\end{enumerate}



\end{document} 


Well your redefinition doesn't contain the new tagging code. So naturally it breaks.

@UlrikeFischer, i copied the code \@startsection from latex-lab-testphase-sec.sty  from latex-lab bundle then also correct tag also not applied, how to redefine the \@startsection

your MWE doesn't show any tagging code. So no, you didn't copy it correctly.
